# Neo4j - How to delete unused property keys from browser?

Tags: neo4j, nosql

I've deleted all my nodes and relationships ([Delete all nodes and relationships in neo4j 1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14252591/delete-all-nodes-and-relationships-in-neo4j-1-8)), but I see that in Neo4j Browser the "property keys" that existed before the deletion remain.

See the picture below:

[image]

How can I make all the "Property Keys" go away too, so I can end up with a fresh new database? I understand this orphan property keys do not pose a problem themselves, but they clutter the browser experience and will start confusing with newer properties.

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't have any data you want to keep, you can just delete the whole database and create a new one. Unfortunately that doesn't help when you have data you want to keep, *short of* exporting it and re-importing it into a new database.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should be able to clear everything out by:

- stopping your Neo4j database
- deleting everything matching `data/graph.db/*` (look inside the `graph.db` folder)
- starting up again.

Comment: OK, that did the trick, thanks! But what I wanted to know is how to remove unused properties. Suppose I didn't want to complete erase my database, just the property keys of deleted nodes that I won't be needing anymore. Is there a way of doing that?

Comment: I'm not sure, unfortunately.  Hopefully somebody will step in here, otherwise I would visit the Neo4j public Slack channel: http://neo4j.com/blog/public-neo4j-users-slack-group/

Comment: Didn't like having to delete the directory content but it worked. There should be a better way to do this.

Comment: I don't disagree ;)  I believe that a "TRUNCATE" style command is on the todo list for the Neo folks

Comment: I can't find the `data/graph.db` folder anywhere on my OSX installation of Neo4j...

Comment: Matt: Which version of Neo4j are you using?  In 3.0 (just recently released as a release candidate), they changed the folder structure around some

Comment: for property keys delete neostore.propertystore.db.* files only

Comment: In version 5 the path is `data/databases/neo4j/neostore.propertystore.db.*`

Answer (score 1):

What version of Neo4j are you using? Prior to to version 2.3 there is a file named `keystore` in the `data/` directory that was used to populate this in the browser. Deleting this file will clear out the Labels, Relationship Types, and Property Keys listed in the browser.

Looks like this has changed now with Neo4j 2.3 so if you are using the latest version I don't think you'll have this file.

Answer (score 1):

In the manual you can see that there is currently no way to disentangle which property keys are currently used without traversing the graph.

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-property-values.html#_property_keys

Which is a bummer because I'd like to do the same thing. TBC.

Comment: Looks like there's no way in v3.0.1. Tried deleting various combinations of `neostore.propertystore.*` but it just screws up the database in different ways. Seems like you just have to live with it until Neo fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have Neo4j Community Edition 3.2. To get rid of the property keys (and get rid of the entire DB), I completely uninstalled Neo4j, deleted the Neo4j folder in C:\Program Files and then reinstalled the package again so that I had a fresh DB to work with. Not ideal to delete everything but it worked for me.

Comment: you sure didn't need to reinstall the operating system as well? ;)

Comment: me too, had to take a bath later as well :/

Answer (score 1):

I got rid of the properties by open a new DB.|(I didn't want to delete my old folder )
Create a new folder beside the default folder 
stop the server 
choose the new folder and start again a new DB with new PW

Answer (score -1):

Actually, there is not a way to just delete the unused properties. You need to recreate the graph or use a tool to copy neo4j stores called "store-utils".