# Delete property keys from Neo4j 3.0

Tags: neo4j

I'm looking how to remove property keys from Neo4j 3.0. I tried :

```
MATCH (n)
DETACH DELETE n
```

But it doesn't delete property keys.
I tried to remove data folder from my graphdb and restart the server but still have the same thing.
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can't really remove the properties from the left pane of the neo4j browser (see [Neo4j - How to delete unused property keys from browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33982639/neo4j-how-to-delete-unused-property-keys-from-browser)).

To remove a property from nodes do:

```
MATCH (n:Node)
REMOVE n.my_key
```

Your query will delete the node itself.

Comment: I tested but no change because I deleted the nodes using this:
MATCH (n)
DETACH DELETE n

But still have the property keys

Comment: Without a node you don't **have** a property key. Maybe it's shown on the left side of the web interface, but you don't have any data.

Comment: Exactly, it's shown on the left side of my interface and now I have a large list. How can I remove it without nodes?

Comment: Not really possible except by deleting the database files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33982639/neo4j-how-to-delete-unused-property-keys-from-browser

Comment: I tried this. Im in windows but still have the same thing

Comment: It works when I delete all Files propertystore.
Thank yiou

Answer (score 2):

To delete the property key from a node:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE EXISTS(n.foo) REMOVE n.foo
```

To delete the property key from a relationship:

```
MATCH ()-[r]->() WHERE EXISTS(r.foo) REMOVE r.foo
```

But even after the property key is deleted, the empty key name will for now remain part of the Database Information list for reason that only Neo4j know.